# Всё(,) что только можно(,) случилось

Tags: запятые

Нужны запятые?

`Всё(,) что только можно(,) случилось.`

`Всё(,) что надо(,) у меня есть.`

`В холодильнике всё(,) что нужно.`

`Я сделал всё(,) что можно.`

Comment: Всё случилось, что только можно, Всё что надо есть у меня, В холодильнике - всё, что нужно. Можно-ль, нужно-ль - сделал, друзья!